# How to interpose cuda runtime API used within tensorflow?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, cuda, ld

I have installed tensorflow (not from source) on an x86-64 Ubuntu  computer with CUDA 10 and a suitable GPU. My goal is to intercept (using LD_PRELOAD) the CUDA runtime API for any tensorflow applications. Unfortunately for my use-case, I am not able to build tensorflow from source for my target machine which is not x86-64.

I am able to intercept the cudaLaunchKernel calls I make from a test program written in C++ that dynamically loads the cuda runtime API, and on first inspection I thought that python should similarly dynamically load the same cuda .so - I am confused because LD_PRELOAD is not working for a normally-installed tensorflow application running with cuda enabled.

I expect that cudaLaunchKernel calls within tensorflow should be intercepted by my interposition library that is LD_PRELOAD'd. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that Tensorflow uses the driver API rather than the runtime API and itself, uses its own  library loading process and bypasses the standard dynamic loader mechanism

Comment: I have successfully caught cu*/Driver API function calls within Tensorflow before, but these could be called from the runtime API or directly. My evidence that TF is using cudaLaunchKernel is both from an nvprof output, which says that cudaLaunchKernel is used to launch kernels, and this source in TF's code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8a653bd99c69602675fc9926f201985e65c980be/tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h#L331. I am also interposing dlsym, and I don't find that TF's using this to dynamically load the runtime API (it _is_ for the driver api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Tensorflow wrote stream_executor to avoid having to use CUDA's Runtime API, and instead wrap CUDA's Driver API (cuLaunchKernel) itself with opensource code. 
This is referenced in this 
[Pull Request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/19797) to Tensorflow to allow interposing of CUDA's Runtime API, which was rejected. As well, in TF source (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.h)), we see that cu*/driver API is actively being used instead of the runtime API.

Comment: Just because stream_executor may be trying to replace cuda's runtime API, it's not true to say that Tensorflow is completely rid of CUDA runtime calls, as show above. In fact, you can still find some kernel ops called from cuda's runtime api, such as FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch, which is used in common randomizing code like:
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,2,2,1]))